# User can't delete this request: Unknown error

Tags: facebook, request

I'm trying delete an request using the following code:

```
function deleteRequest(<request_id>_<user_id>) { 
    FB.api(<request_id>_<user_id>, 'delete', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
```

But facebook returns the following error:

**message: "(#2) User can't delete this request: Unknown error"**

**type: "OAuthException"**

What is going on?

Comment: can you delete the request via http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you removing request with JS-SDK and not providing `access_token` explicitly (which means `access_token` for current user is used) this may be related to couple of things:

- Active user is not the one who received this request.
- Active user isn't application user yet.

Things to do:

- Ensure you authorized user before trying to remove request.
- Check that `FB.getAuthResponse().userID` is the same as `<user_id>`

Comment: This action  do not  providing access_token explicitly, because is sent by the logged user (current user) to other user that have this app.
 - Really user can not be the one to receive the request, but this problem is solved using the format  (_ <request_id> <user_id>), thus uniquely identifying the request to be deleted.
 - All users who are involved (sender / receiver) have the app
 - The attempted exclusion is made ​​by the user logged in, where this user has added application.

Comment: - No, FB.getAuthResponse().userID is the id of the current user, and the <user_id> is id of the user who received the current user request.  In other words, are different. This is a problem?
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was passing the id of the User that generated the request, but the correct is pass user_id of the user that received request.

Answer (score 0):

If user is not [active user is not the one who received this request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763021/user-cant-delete-this-request-unknown-error/8763233#8763233) you can also use application access token (`APPID|APPSECRET`), however use it **ONLY(!) in backend (not in javascript!)** because of security reasons.